# jQuery Mobile page transitions aren't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, jquery-mobile, handlebars.js

I'm implementing a custom MVC structure using Handlebars and jQuery Mobile. In order to handle routing manually, I've disabled two jQM parameters:

```
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

These two lines disable jQuery Mobile link binding and hash listening. Everything seems to work fine until I want to use a page transition other than `fade`. When I re-enable link binding, the page transitions start working but funny things start happening (e.g. the title of the page is displayed as {{page}} because jQM pulls this out of the HTML before Handlebars compiles it).

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="/styles/jquery.mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" >
  <script src="/script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/script/jquery.mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/script/handlebars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="one" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header"><h1>{{page}}</h1></div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>
      {{content}}
      <a href="#two" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">Two</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="two" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header"><h1>{{page}}</h1></div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>
      {{content}}
      <a href="#one" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">One</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var count = 0;
function one() {
  return({page: 'One', content: 'One is the loneliest number.'});
}

function two() {
  return({page: 'Two', content: 'Two is company.'});
}

// Handle link binding and hash changes manually
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;

// Router
$(window).bind('load hashchange', function() {
  var hash = '#one';
  if (location.hash.length > 0) {
    hash = location.hash;
  }
  var source = $(hash).html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(window[hash.substring(1, hash.length)]());
  $(hash).html(html);
  $.mobile.changePage(hash);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will really need to take a look at rewriting how and where you call your animations in the jqm structure.

pagebeforechange, pagebeforeload, pagebeforecreate, etc.. If you have shut off the ajax you are disabling alot of this functionality. I don't think you are going to find a singular answer that will solve your problem outright. We struggled with it as well and finally had to find a compromise and a lot of testing to find the right combination of usage with our templating structures (pure.js).

Answer (score 0):

Jquery mobile transitions work well in native apps. Using plugins causes a lot of distortion. If you really want that animation, I suggest you do not use any plugins.

Comment: I don't really think this is a practical answer. You're saying that if you use jQuery Mobile, you can't use any jQuery plugins?

Comment: You can, but transitions are very buggy. I tried using plugins with phone gap/cordova and the only one that worked was sliding up between transitions and that didn't look cool so I eventually let it go, when I tested without cordova, it worked.You could try listening to pagebeforeshow and pagehide and not having fixed headers but with a plugin debugging is tough because you have other templates determining how your pages are rendered unlike with a native app, you know what you did and can easily eliminate errors.